# SQL Server 2012: incorrect syntax near 'order' on windowing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This should be a straight forward partition over/order by... but I've got the *dumb* today and can't see the error of my wicked ways.

Here's the schema and sql:

```
create table #NoDiscountFleet
(fleet_number int,
 customer_key int,
 posyear int,
 posmonth int,
 sale_net_val  decimal(16,4),
 sale_tot_qty decimal(12,3),
 FirstDayOfMonth date,
 LastDayOfMonth date
);

select  fleet_number,
        lastdayofmonth,
        tot_fleet_net_sales = sum(sale_net_val) over (partition by fleet_number order by fleet_number,lastdayofmonth)
from #NoDiscountFleet
 group by fleet_number,lastdayofmonth
      order by fleet_number;
```

Comment: i have it in the order by over the partition by fleet number--so--it should be 1 of the drivers for the aggregate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT  fleet_number,
        lastdayofmonth,
        tot_fleet_net_sales = SUM(sale_net_val) OVER (PARTITION BY fleet_number 
                                                      ORDER BY lastdayofmonth)
FROM #NoDiscountFleet
ORDER BY fleet_number;
```

Comment: @plditallo Then are you sure that you are using a database with SQL Server 2012?, because that syntax works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8c118/2

Comment: ...I KNEW I had the *dumb* today! I usually am on an mssql2012 server... but today... I'm not--I'm on a 2008 r2 instance pared down for 2005 compatibility which I did not pay attention to until you validated the syntax on your instance. Thank you so much--because I would have no doubt wasted yet even more time on this!

Comment: @plditallo don't worry, this happens more often than many want to admit